# shell_exec() return results before command execution is complete

Tags: php

I'm trying to run an anti-virus scan using PHP and it works fine, but when scanning large files > 1GB the command returns a partial results without the actual scan results. Which I assume is because the command execution timed out before the execution is complete because it takes a long time. is there a way to force the php to wait for the execution completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout PHP's `max_execution_time`

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time